# On Mac OS X, how do I turn a POSIX fd into a FILE*?

Tags: c, macos, file, posix

I'm working with a lexer that accepts `FILE*` objects to read data from. I'd like to be able to pass it POSIX file descriptors (i.e. stuff you get from `open`, pipes, etc.).

How can I turn a POSIX file descriptor into a `FILE*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On any POSIX-compliant system, you use [`fdopen()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fdopen.3.html).

Comment: Note that if you want to be able to `fclose` the `FILE *` without destroying your fd, you might want to `dup` the fd first.

Comment: (And of course pass the `dup`'d copy to `fdopen` rather than passing the original.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `fdopen(3)` in `<stdio.h>`.